# How do I get the actual property values of my model from Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to get all objects for an entity. I execute an NSFetchRequest and the objects are returned successfully in "fault" format. My question is, how can I take it a step further and access the actual object properties in my fetch result? This seems like it should be simple, yet I am missing something. Specifically, how I do get the values out of "result" below. I have tried iterating through result, assigning the current object to an NSDictionary, then accessing the object properties via objectForKey, but that did not work. I have read through apple developer documentation, online forums, stack overflow questions with no luck. Please help! I can save data to the database. BUT How do you get the freakin data OUT of the database using core data!!??

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default objects will return as faults but as soon as you access any data it should work. For instance, if your MyEntity has a value called "name" you should be able to do

```
for (MyEntity *myEntity in result) {
  NSLog(@"My entity name: %@", myEntity.name);
}
```

and you should get the results you expect.